# JAX-RS PathParam not working

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

Trying to allow forward slashes using JAX-RS `@PathParam`.  What happens is that it takes the backend of the value and not the whole value.  Example below

**METHOD CODE**

```
@PUT
@POST
@Path("/temp/{keyValue:.+}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public void setValues(@PathParam("keyValue") PathSegment myvalue) {
  for (String key : myvalue.getMatrixParameters().keySet()) {
    System.out.println(batch)
  }
```

**TEST URL**

```
https://localhost:8443/*path*/temp/keyValue;key1=THIS/SUCKS
```

**RESULT**

```
batch = SUCKS
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
batch = key1=THIS/SUCKS
```

I have tried changing the regex in the method signature and I can not make this work.  If things are url encoded, I am able to get it pass through with the `%2F`.  However, if I change my Apache httpd to `AllowEncodedSlashes On`, it would break the rest of my site.  Any ideas on what it could be?

I am running httpd -> tomcat -> restService (JAX-RS)

Comment: Your parameter *must* be URL encoded.

Comment: I tried that, but httpd needed to be switched to allow encodings.  That would have broke other parts of my site.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work correctly, so I rewrote it so that it accepts a string that is converted to a JSON object.  Sending parameters in a URL string is a bad idea because URLs have a character limit.  I am now sending it as data in an AJAX call.